# Node.js Heroku app crashes with Error R10 (Boot timeout) `heroku restart` not working

Tags: node.js, heroku

Using the below code from an example I found, my Heroku Node.js app crashes. It is not responding when I navigate to [myapp].herokuapp.com

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var counter = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

// increment the counter for each visitor request
counter=counter+1;

var path = req.url;
console.log("requested=" + path + " counter=" + counter);

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); // prepare response headers

res.end(" :) "); 

}).listen(port);
```

my procfile is

```
web: node thenameofmyapp.js
```

I have done `heroku ps:scale web=1`

I had some dependencies but removed them to try to get a simple app to work. My current package.json is

```
{
  "name": "thenameofmyapp",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

Why can't my app bind to the port?

EDIT: It looks like even after multiple updates and running `heroku restart`, my app is still running code that doesn't exist anymore. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what happened, but it looked like Heroku was not restarting when I pushed new code or ran `heroku restart`. I created a new app with the same code and it works.

One difference someone else might want to test is that I removed node_packages from my git repo before pushing to the new app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check what is happening with your app by doing: heroku logs (you have to install the herokucli before).

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by a process that is not able to reach an external resource or it has to many code dependencies, or there's to many evaluations, parsing during start.